# State machine in C for SDL game

Tags: c, state-machine, sdl2

I want to create a state machine for menu in my SDL game. So this is my code without the SDL. I just want to ask if this is a good way to create it. I am trying to implement a screen and then mouse events, but I have a problem there so this is a reason why I ask if this is okay. Here is a code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h> 
enum states
{
Menu,
Game,
Game_over,
Exit
};

int main()
{
int game_is_running = 1;
enum states state = Menu;
while(game_is_running == 1)
{
  switch(state)
{
 case Menu:
state = Game;
printf("menu screen with play and exit button.\n"); //need to add if 
                                            //exit or play is pressed 
                 // if exit then exit program if play than you know...
 break;
case Game:
 state = Game_over;
printf("after play button is pressed game screen will show up.\n"); //after this i will come back to menu.
break;
case Game_over:
state = Exit;
printf("screen after game.\n");
break;
case Exit:
printf("turn game off.\n"); //this will be in the if function with a game.
game_is_running = 0;
break;
}
Sleep(1000); // sleep for a second just for test
}
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that really how your code is formatted?

Comment: it's not the exact same but its a first thing what i post here. In the meantime i put switch state in a void and in the main function i just put a name of void function

Comment: Code Review is for reviews of complete code that is working as intended. If you want to have an opinion on how to best structure your game code, try asking at the [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or the [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) sites.